# Wildcards: How to exclude a string? (Does not contain)

Tags: wildcards

I was practicing the use of **wildcards** today .. that was a lot of fun. 
The most complex thing that worked out exactly as I was expecting was: 
`ls [![:digit:]]*[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][aA-zZ]*[![:digit:]]`

But I didn't actually manage to exclude a string. 
How can I list only files which **do not contain** "test"? 
Here some examples what I've tried already:

```bsh
ls *!("test")*
ls !("test")
ls !=*"test"*
ls !(*"test"*)
ls *^test*
ls *(^test)*
ls (^test)*
ls !test*
ls !*test*
ls *!test*
ls !{test}
ls !*{test}*
ls *!{test}*
```

Comment: To get appropriate answers, you should specify which *shell* you are using

Comment: GNU bash, version 5.0.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ touch a b c test
$ ls !(*test*)
a  b  c
```

Comment: Make it `!(*test*)` to exclude anything with `test` in the front, middle or end. `!(*test)` would only exclude names where `test` appears at the end.

Comment: @ilkkachu: thx, applied

Comment: Thanks man, that finally worked! Even with combined lower + upper case option `ls !(*[Tt][Ee][Ss][Tt]*)`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively and portably you can use `find` command as following:

```
find -type f ! -name '*test*'
```